# Are there infinite many primes p such that 2p-1 is also prime?

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers

I did a search online and found a similar notion called Sophie Germain prime, which by definition is a prime $p$ such that $2p+1$ is also prime. Sophie Germain primes are conjectured to be of infinite many. I wonder if anyone has thought of the similar question replacing $2p+1$ by $2p-1$.

Comment: Yes, I'm afraid that many people have thought of this, and it is just as unsolved as the $2p+1$ case (it is widely believed that there are infinitely many).  Sophie Germain didn't get primes named after her just for asking the question; those primes are named in honour of their role in her work on Fermat's Last Theorem.

Comment: if so they all have to be 1 mod 6

Comment: The commutative associative operator $(x,y) \rightarrow 2xy-x-y+1$ sends integers to integers and has a set of primes naturally associated with it. The intersection of the normal primes with these primes is precisely normal primes P such that (P-1)/2 is also a normal prime which is the same set the OP is interested in.

Comment: @SidharthGhoshal Why is that notable?  The operator you give is just multiplication conjugated by $x\mapsto 2x-1$, with the caveat that this map is not really a bijection on $\mathbb Z$ so it relies on the fact that odd times odd is odd.  But we can play the same game with other maps: $kxy + x + y$ is commutative and associative for any $k$.  What's special about $2x-1$?

Comment: It felt like an interesting way to restate OPs problem at the time.

Answer (score 3):

These primes are tabulated at http://oeis.org/A005382
They don't seem to have a name, though they are related to [Cunningham chains](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cunningham_chain).

Answer (score 0):

I have managed to find a proof such that all Sophie Germain primes are of the prime form $6n-1$, but have failed to get further. My proof is:

If the primes created by the formula $2x + 1$ equals the prime type $4y + 1$, the equation of $2x + 1 = 4y + 1$ is created, which simplifies to $x = 2y$. But as $x$ is prime, $x$ cannot equal anything but $2$. Therefore, the Germain safe primes are of the prime type $4y – 1$. This creates the equation $2x + 1 = 4y – 1$, which simplifies to $x = 2y - 1$. That means both $4y – 1$ and $2y – 1$ needs to be prime.

This will never be true of the values of $y$ that are of the formula $3n + 2$, excluding $2$. This is because the first value of $y$ in the equation $2y – 1 (5)$ makes $9$, and each new term in the sequence is the last term $+ 2$. After $3$ places, you add $6$, making a new multiple of $3$.

This leads the terms in the formula $3n$. Let us substitute $y$ for $3n$. $2(3n) – 1$ simplifies to $6n – 1$. For $3n – 1$, the other formula, you produce $6n + 1$.

For hypothetical $6n + 1$ Germain primes, the safe prime would be $12n + 3$. As terms from the formula $12n + 3$ will always divide by three, the only possible Germain prime is where $n = 0$. As the Germain "prime" would be $1$, and as $1$ is not prime, there are no safe primes of the formula $12n + 3$. Therefore, all Germain primes must be from the formula $6n - 1$.

Comment: Every odd prime is of the form $6n\pm 1$ except for the prime $3.$  If the prime $p$ is greater than $3$ and $p=6n+1$ then $2p+1=12n+3=3(4n+1),$ which is $>3$ and divisible by $3,$ so is not prime..... On the other hand, $3 $  $is$  a  Germain prime.