# Pair of primes of the form $4k+3$ and $8k+5$?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers

This homework is optional, but I find it much harder than the rest of the optional one.

Prove or disprove that there are infinite number of pairs of primes of the form $4k+3$ and $8k+5$ (that is $k$ is integer, not necessarily prime, $4k+3$ and $8k+5$ are both primes).

For example, $19,37$ is such a pair for $k=4$.

We just learn Dirichlet theorem last week (no proofs though), so there should be an infinite number of prime of each type, but it is not clear why both should happen. Is there something inside the proof of the theorem that could help?

So I am guessing this is a disprove question, since I no know techniques to prove it. But all I can do is to try some modulo, and none work. So help?

Comment: Sounds like a hard problem

Comment: Sounds like an unsolved problem.

Comment: This looks related: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/911690/are-there-infinite-many-primes-p-such-that-2p-1-is-also-prime

Comment: Related: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/220562/primes-p-for-which-2p-1-is-prime

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an open Q in mathematics. More generally,for  prime p for which 2p-1 is also prime :  Whether there is a largest one, or a largest one in some infinite congruence class (such as congruent to 3, mod 4) is unknown.Most, if not all,variants of this Q (e.g. a Sophie Germain prime p , where 2p+1 is also prime) are also open Q's.

Comment: Any sources? It's clear about the Sophie Germain primes, but give sources for the other problems.

Comment: sorry i can't recall..iit's been a while. try wikipedia.

Comment: Thank you, the professor said it is only there for us to think about it, it's not meant to be solved, and we only need to write a heuristic argument. So is it okay if I said that there are nothing in the polynomial that prevent them from being primes at the same time, so by pseudorandomness of prime it should happen at roughly the square of Li?

Comment: Intuitively ,it seems reasonable. It has been shown that, asymptotically ,half the primes are congruent to 3 mod 4, but this is apparently not elementary,even with the Prime Number Theorem.