# Is there a name for primes $p$ for which $2p-1$ is also prime?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers, terminology

What is the name for primes $p$ where $2p-1$ is also a prime?

$2p+1$ is a Sophie Germain prime.

On average if $p$ is a primes how many primes of form $2p^n-1$ could we expect where $0<n<B$ hold?

Comment: @N.S.JOHN not duplicate I do not ask if there are infinite and I ask for *expected* value.

Comment: In the comment Eric Wong mentions there are no particular names for such primes. Not possible duplicate but related

Comment: yes related not duplicates. so you could remove possible duplicate tags.

Comment: Related: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/911690/are-there-infinite-many-primes-p-such-that-2p-1-is-also-prime

Comment: I remember that a program for sieving factors out of given numbers called a chain of primes $p$ , $2p-1$ , $2(2p-1)-1$ and so on a Mersenne chain. Not sure, whether this is common.

Comment: Judging by http://oeis.org/A005382, there doesn't seem to be a name for these primes. But if you really want them named, I suggest "second kind Cunningham chained prime"... on second thought, maybe not.

Answer (score 0):

As a few commentors pointed out, there is no name for such primes. This is because proving anything about primes of the form $2p+1$ would likely correlate to a similar solution to primes of the form $2p-1$, so we don't need a different category for them.

There is an [OEIS](http://oeis.org/A005382) sequence for the primes you are asking about, and it seems they are unnamed as well.